# specify classpath of app launched from intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, I have setup a runtime configuration for a Java (console) application. I need to add the directory `c:/tmp` to the classpath that the app is run with. I guess I need to add `-cp c:/tmp` to one of the boxes in this dialog, but I can't figure out which one:

[image]

Comment: What you are trying to do? Is the tmp dir a classpath specific to only this run config? Otherwise, you already specifying a classpath, using the field "Use classpath of this module", and you have to change the classpath in the module configuration

Comment: The tmp dir should only be added to the classpath for this run config

Comment: The VM parameter field let you put the options for the VM, including the classpath, but I think (not sure) you also have to disable the "use classpath and jdk..." or at least check which one take precedence

Answer (score 2):

Classpath is configured in the [Module Dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

Answer (score 0):

The classpath is a VM parameter, so it should belong in there. However, I'm unsure whether you can overwrite the classpath at all using this technique...

If you want to specify the classpath for adding additional jars, you should use libraries instead.

Also, are you sure you want to change the classpath and not the working folder? (The classpath determines where to find classes, the working folder defines the starting directory of your application.)